# Inserting form data from Ionic to MySQL DB doesn't work

Tags: php, mysql, angularjs, ionic-framework

Well, I am trying to insert data from an Ionic form to an MySQL database using a PHP server, i've followed [this tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1005150/Posting-data-from-Ionic-app-to-PHP-server).

But when I try to insert data on the database it doesn't work.

Here's the code:

**insertProdutos.html**

```html
<ion-view title="Products" id="page4" class=" " ng-controller="DataCtrl">
    <ion-content padding="true" class="has-header">
      <form id="form-promocao" class="list " ng-submit="submit()">
          <p id="" style="margin-top:3px;color:#44729C;text-align:center;" class=" ">Entre com as informações do produto</p>
          <ion-list id="cadastro-promocao" class=" ">
            <a href="#"></a>
              <label class="item item-input " id="codigoDoProduto">
                  <input type="number" placeholder="Codigo de barras..." ng-model="data.codigo">
              </label>
              <label class="item item-input " id="nomeDoProduto">
                  <input type="text" placeholder="Nome do produto..."ng-model="data.nome_produto">
              </label>
     <label class="item item-input " id="tipo_comercializacao">
                  <input type="text" placeholder="Tipo de comercializacao..."ng-model="data.tipo_comercializacao">
              </label>
              <label class="item item-input " id="Medida">
                  <input type="number" placeholder="Medida..." ng-model="data.medida">
              </label>
     <label class="item item-input " id="Peso">
                  <input type="number" placeholder="Peso..." ng-model="data.peso">
              </label>
              <input class="button button-block button-positive" 
                    type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit to server" >
          </ion-list>
      </form>
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

**controllers.js**

```js
.controller('DataCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
 $scope.data = {};
 
    $scope.submit = function(){
  
  var link="http://localhost/PHPserver/api.php"
 
   $http.post(link, {id_produto: $scope.data.codigo, nome_produto: $scope.data.nome_produto, medida_produto: $scope.data.medida, peso_produto: $scope.data.peso, tipo_comercializacao: $scope.data.tipo_comercializacao}).then(function (res){
            $scope.response = res.data;
      });  
     
    }; 
});
```

**api.php**

```html
<?php  
 
 if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'])) {
        header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: {$_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']}");
        header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
        header('Access-Control-Max-Age: 86400');    // cache for 1 day
    }

    // Access-Control headers are received during OPTIONS requests
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'OPTIONS') {

        if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_METHOD']))
            header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS");         

        if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_HEADERS']))
            header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers:        
            {$_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_HEADERS']}");

        exit(0);
    }

   
    $postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");
 if (isset($postdata)) {
  include("connect.php");
  $request = json_decode($postdata);
  $codigo = $request->codigo;
  $produto = $request->nome_produto;
  $medida = $request->medida;
  $tipoComercializacao= $request->tipo_comercializacao;
  $peso = $request->peso;
  
  $sql="INSERT INTO produto(id_produto, nome_produto,peso,tipo_comercializacao,valor_medida) VALUES('".$codigo."','".$produto."','".$peso."','".$tipoComercializacao."','".$medida."')";
  
  if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
   echo "New record created successfully";
  } else {
   echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
  }
 }
?>
```

When I insert the data on the form and press "Submit to server", nothing happens, it doesn't submit and I get no erros on console log.

I would appreciate some help here.
Thank you :)

Comment: Can you clarify, "Doesn't work"?  Do you see any error messages?  Does your ajax request send?  What status code do you get back?

Comment: I've improved the question